# Using Spring Security 5.1.4, is it possible to have a custom HttpFirewall for a specific url-pattern?

Tags: spring-security

I have this config for dav-requets (using Milton, which handles it's own security, for all URLs after /dav/**):

```
<security:http pattern='/dav/**' create-session="never" security="none"/>

<bean id="davRequestsHttpFirewall"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall"
      p:unsafeAllowAnyHttpMethod="true"/>
<security:http-firewall ref="davRequestsHttpFirewall"/>
```

This will result in this implementation of HttpFirewall being used for all requests.

So, $title?